# A sequence about you (Puzzling Stack Exchange users)

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

I have a mysterious sequence for you...

$204, 186, 172, 133, 126, 123, 120, 119, 111, 107, 102, 96, 90, 87, 86, 86, 85, 79, 75, 73, 70, 68, 66, 66, 65, 65, 65, 64, 64, 64, ...$

This sequence may change over time, so I made a website that (should) always show you the current sequence. It's not *that* likely to change often so the website only updates once a day.

https://puzzleforthepuzzlers.pythonanywhere.com/

**Question:** Find the next elements of the sequence.

Hint 1:

> You won't find any hints in the source code or the domain or server response or something like this. It's really about the sequence. If it couldn't change, I would **not** need any server.

Another small hint:

> The title of this question is a hint.

Comment: Hopefully not too easy. ;-)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @GordonAllocman Sorry, edited.

Comment: Well I've officially changed the sequence. Some were quite good that I hadn't seen before!

Comment: -1 This puzzle is based on a snapshot in time that cannot be seen later by interested parties. Even now, just a few hours later, it's not possible to verify.

Comment: @SetBigO I just edited the question for you. Yesterday the webserver didn't work like expected so I removed it but now everything should be fine. So the sequence gets automatically updated over time. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like:

> It continues (as of now) ..., 63, 63, 62, 61, 60, ...
>
>  Because it is the number of votes (up minus down) of the [top-rated questions ever on this site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes).

Comment: Damn, I knew it is too easy.

Comment: But interesting to look at.  Only one at 200 so far!

Comment: @DanRussell only single one over 200 :0

Comment: And credit to @Alconja for 3 of the first 6!