# A puzzling data-driven sequence

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

First puzzle! I was inspired by [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35556/a-sequence-about-you-puzzling-stack-exchange-users) to make my own. Props to the author for itching my brain!

**Update:** I double-checked the sequence, turns out it changed! I overlooked something which I have now made a note of in Hint 3. You are now trying to find the **13th** number instead of the **14th**.

**Update 2:** Updated the sequence again.

---

What is $x$ in this sequence?

$3,1,203,3,1,1,0,4,4,2,1,0,x,0,...$

This can be solved using only information that is found on [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/?cmVwZGl2aWQ=).

Hint:

> Think about the linked question. This sequence can be solved in a similar way.

Hint 2:

> This sequence also changes, but not as often as the linked question.

Hint 3:

> The bigger numbers change more often than the smaller ones.

**Key Hint (updated):**

> 3 digits, 2 numbers, 1 op. All-time high.

**Key Hint 2 (updated):**

> There is a code hidden in the Puzzling.SE link.

**Key Hint 3:**

> All the information can be found on a single list of users on a single page.

**Key Hint 4 (final?):**

> Integer division is involved. The code from Key Hint 2 describes the operation.

Comment: When it changes, is the change significant?

Comment: The maximum change I would expect at one time would be two numbers swapping places, or one number increasing or decreasing by 1.

Comment: I would say the list represents the upvotes for the questions or answers of one of the users on Puzling SE. I'm trying to find who it is.

Comment: @Marius Nope. Wrong track. Check the key hint. (Though that's an awesome idea I will promptly steal :D)

Comment: After further review, I actually found some changes I missed in the sequence! Updated accordingly.

Comment: And what's up with the 14th number? Vanished?..

Comment: @nicael Just forgot. Reworded question slightly to make position clearer.

Comment: Is this related to tags anyhow? I think I've looked absolutely everywhere...

Comment: Also, does Puzzling have an option to sort that sequence?

Comment: @nicael No tags, but the order of data is important here. Think about the Key Hint, especially the last part. Key Hint 2 should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Oh... check the puzzling link? You're referring anti-cache? What's with it :/

Comment: @nicael How come do you know it's anti-cache. Am I missing something?

Comment: @nicael It's not anything to do with cache. Added Key Hint 3.

Comment: @Real This has nothing to do with puzzles, it just looks like a common cache-breaker :)

Comment: So no deciphers or similar stuff?

Comment: @nicael It seems that the link is causing more trouble than help. I'll update the hint about the link for a final push. Maybe I didn't categorize or explain this puzzle correctly. :/

Comment: And you say this is inspired by _my question_? I can't find an answer for this. :(

Comment: Any experienced puzzler should be able to see that the link is base64 for "rep divide", I don't think you needed to give more hints about that.

Comment: @ffao Ah, **but is it?**

Comment: Hmm... In that case I appreciate the hints haha

Comment: @ffao Play with the text a little more.

Comment: Hasn't the sequence changed yet?

Comment: And by the way, is the original hint still a hint?..

Comment: Also, that's nice.  We've already used a decoder, and puzzling.se doesn't have this tool. Now we should use something else to determine what to divide...

Comment: Why should you complicate the question with integer division at all?.. It's already difficult (or inpossible) to answer.

Comment: @nicael Ugh, you're right. It was even more often than I thought. :/

Comment: @nicael You are right on all counts. I guess I was very ambitious for my first question and failed to understand the implications that a changing sequence would have. Should I just answer it myself at this point since everyone seems to be stuck?

Comment: Probably, and please get the next question with a less difficult sequence ;) I'm quite interested to know the answer, but others might be not that delighted to see the riddle answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to my misunderstanding of how difficult this puzzle actually is, and by recommendation of other users active here, I've decided to answer it myself. Hopefully this will illustrate my train of thought as I built it.

---

The sequence is from

> the list of Puzzling.SE users with all-time highest reputation, found here: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all
>
>  [image: modified view]
>
>  The image above is slightly modified. I expanded the rep for each of the users so you see `31758` instead of `31.7k`, as well as appended the ID for each user next to their name. The concept is the same.

To find the sequence,

> take the list of users in order, starting from the one with the highest rep. **Divide each user's reputation by their ID, discarding the decimal.**
>
>  For the first user (Gamow), the calculation would be $31758 / 8874 = \lfloor3.578769...\rfloor = 3$.
>  Second (f''): $24004 / 12408 = \lfloor1.934558...\rfloor = 1$.
>  Third (Joe Z.): $17867 / 88 = \lfloor203.034090...\rfloor = 203$.
>
>  Following this pattern, the 13th member of the sequence can be found:
>  $9032 / 28 = \lfloor322.571428...\rfloor = 322$.
>
>  Thus, $x$ is $322$.

Explanation of key hints:

> **3 digits, 2 numbers, 1 op. All-time high.** The answer has three digits, which can be found using two numbers and one mathematical operation (dividing reputation by the ID of all-time high reputation users).
>
>  **There is a code hidden in the Puzzling.SE link.** The Base64-encoded string at the end of the link decodes to `repdivid`, or `rep div id` (reputation divide ID).
>
>  **All the information can be found on a single list of users on a single page.** The snapshot of the page above makes the necessary information obvious, but the exact reputation can be found without modifying the page by hovering the rep count of a user. The ID can be found by hovering the user's link and noting the number in the address.
>
>  **Integer division is involved. The code from Key Hint 2 describes the operation.** This is a directive to drop the decimal place of each calculation to find the correct sequence member.

Comment: [+1] very nice indeed.                                      .

Comment: I wonder if we can sort users by "reputation / ID number". klm123 is higher than me, but [Kevin](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4/kevin) is higher than both of us.

Comment: Wow I was so close...I was dividing Reputation by the number of posts for each all-time high user...forgot to think outside of the box. Also, the fact that your Base64 code spelled "repdivid" and not "repdivide" had me going on some wild goose chase lol...

Comment: Huh, this was really difficult...

Comment: @nicael That's on me. I'm working in a new (different) puzzle, hopefully will be more straightforward and fun. :)

Answer (score 0):

## PARTIAL ANSWER

So I can't comment yet, so I'll post what I've tried (and a question to OP)

Basically, I've mostly tried doing stuff on this nifty [page](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/new), which allows you to query data on Puzzling using SQL. I've tried relating (all with regards to Puzzling SE):

Reputation for a user

UpVotes & DownVotes for a user

Age, Account CreationDate,  for users

Score for Posts, Answers, and Comments

and more...

Also I'm terrible with ciphers, so if someone would like to volunteer their findings regarding Key Hint 2, that would be great.

**Question for OP:** Does Key Hint 3 refer to ONE user's profile? Or a list of multiple users?

Comment: You are on the right track! Understanding Key Hint 2 is very important in this case. In regard to Key Hint 3, I'm speaking of a **list of users**, rather than a **user's list.** I will clarify the hint.

Comment: @cyber What? Since when is the Data explorer on the same domain as Puzzling.SE and why is it the right track?

Comment: @nicael Using the Data Explorer is not what I meant by "on the right track." It is fully possible to answer this puzzle using only information readily available from Puzzling.SE exclusively. Using Data Explorer may make it easier, however.

Comment: @aznbanana After re-reading your post, actually you aren't **totally** correct. You only need to look at _one_ list to solve the sequence.

Comment: All-time high... Maybe high-rep users? Moderators? Something like that? http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/498831

Comment: @palsch Closer!

Comment: @cyber *How* using Data explorer can help solve the probem if it updates once a week on Sunday? The data is outdated most of the time.

Comment: @nicael The original sequence was generated from the Data Explorer, before I realized that it was only updated weekly. The pattern is still recognizable in the Data Explorer, it would just report an incorrect final answer, so the solution would have to be found by hand, which is not difficult to do.